# Showing that Newton's polynomial basis is a basis for $\mathcal{P}_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am surprised that this proof is not included in any of my course materials, but the claim is that the Newton's basis polynomials $n(x)_k = \prod_{j = 0}^{k - 1}(x - x_j), n_0(x) = 1$ are a basis for the space $\mathcal{P}_n$ of polynomials of degree at most $n$. That is one has to show that any polynomial $p(x) = c_0\cdot 1 + c_1\cdot(x - x_0) + \dots + c_n\cdot\prod_{j = 0}^{n - 1}(x - x_j)$ can also be represented with the basis polynomials $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$.

Currently the only "proof" I can give is that since the coefficients $c_0,\dots,c_n$ are arbitrary, once we have opened up and simplified the polynomial expression in Newton's basis polynomials, we can surely choose proper coefficients for $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose some linear combination of these functions vanishes. Put $x=x_1$ to see that the coefficient of $n_0$ must be $0$. Then divide by $x-x_1$ and put $x=x_2$ to see that the next coefficient is $0$ and so on. This proves that the given functions are linearly independent. Since $\mathcal P_n$ has dimension $n+1$ it follows that your functions form a basis for it.

Comment: When you say "some linear combination of these functions vanishes", which functions do you refer to? Do you mean some polynomial $p(x)$ which comprises of both Newton's basis polynomials and polynomials from $\{1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n\}$?

Comment: @EpsilonAway I am starting with $c_0n_0(x)+c_1n_1(x)+...+c_n n_n(x)=0$ and proving that each $c_i$ is $0$ . (We want to prove linear independence of these products).

Comment: I see. If the Newton's polynomials are linearly independent, then they must form a basis. Makes sense!